# High Memory Utilization in AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have used AWS EC2 t2.large server for my web application.

I have setup the custom metric for MemoryUtilization. After setup, When i viewed the MemoryUtilization Metric, it shows more than 85% almost all time.

Also, I have checked the CPU Utilization for the same instance, it is less than 10% in most of the time.

I am wondering how MemoryUtilization has gone such high? What might be the possible options to reduce them? Is it due to the virtualization system of AWS?

Comment: It's more related to your web application.

Comment: But, my web application is not much memory intensive. I have also read the following document: http://lowendbox.com/blog/how-to-tell-your-xen-vps-is-overselling-memory/ @Sandor

Comment: What does your *MemoryUtilization* metric show? What are you running on the server? Please read and follow the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, do not assume anyone knows what are you thinking/doing (note: I don't think any serious provider would over-commit/oversell memory, that's why we are paying the price)

Comment: connect to your instance and run "top -o %MEM" to see which processes consume highest amount of memory.

Answer (score 2):

Your application has memory leaks or unnecessary memory usage. 
Try using any memory leak detection tools to fix the application. 
If you don't want to fix your application, try changing the instance type to any *Memory Optimized* instance type.